# Unable to add window -- permission denied when trying to create floating view

Tags: java, android

I am currently looking to develop an interface debug tool for Android which would display some system information overlaid on top of whatever app is running underneath. I've look at many different resources online and followed the basic procedure of setting my application to `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` defining the permissions required in my manifest with `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`, however, when trying to run the application the process, it crashes with the error `FATAL EXCEPTION` ... `Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W...` `-- permission denied for window type 2038`.

I tried further investigating what could be causing the problem, and I managed to find out that since a certain version, Android will require for users to explicitly set permissions for apps to draw over other apps via `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`, however, even after enabling permissions to draw over other apps, the process still resulted in the same error.

I currently have my app setup to check whether draw-over permissions have been granted, and asks the user to set it if not. Once it confirms permissions are enabled by the user, it calls the service where I attempt to create an overlaying view.

I'm relatively new to Android development so I would appreciate any ideas or guidance!

**Update**: Managed to get it working by setting the window's LayoutParam to use `TYPE_PHONE` instead of `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`. This is working for Android N, however it may be good to note that this method is deprecated for Android O+

Comment: Could you please add full log of the error?

Comment: Share your  stackTrace

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```